# Imports on angular tests

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an angular project and I have a component to test.Now this componnet has a submodule.ts and the project has a general module.ts and also there is a test.module.ts.
An example of each one of them:

submodule.ts that is a module shared for some componnets.

```html
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { OncosupSharedModule } from '../../shared';
import {
    ProtocoloService,
    ProtocoloPopupService,
    ProtocoloComponent,
    ProtocoloDetailComponent,
    ProtocoloDialogComponent, //testing only this componnet
    ProtocoloPopupComponent,
    ProtocoloDeletePopupComponent,
    ProtocoloDeleteDialogComponent,
    protocoloRoute,
    protocoloPopupRoute,
    ProtocoloResolvePagingParams,
} from './';

const ENTITY_STATES = [
    ...protocoloRoute,
    ...protocoloPopupRoute,
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        OncosupSharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES)
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProtocoloComponent,
        ProtocoloDetailComponent,
        ProtocoloDialogComponent,
        ProtocoloDeleteDialogComponent,
        ProtocoloPopupComponent,
        ProtocoloDeletePopupComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ProtocoloComponent,
        ProtocoloDialogComponent,  //I am only testing this componnet
        ProtocoloPopupComponent,
        ProtocoloDeleteDialogComponent,
        ProtocoloDeletePopupComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProtocoloService,
        ProtocoloPopupService,
        ProtocoloResolvePagingParams,
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

my general.module.ts for all teh project

```html
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        OncosupAppRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        OncosupSharedModule,
        OncosupHomeModule,
        OncosupAdminModule,
        OncosupAccountModule,
        OncosupEntityModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    ],
    declarations: [
        JhiMainComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        PageRibbonComponent,
        ActiveMenuDirective,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService,
        PaginationConfig,
        UserRouteAccessService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                StateStorageService,
                Injector
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                JhiEventManager
            ]
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [
                Injector
            ]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ JhiMainComponent ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class OncosupAppModule {}
```

And my test.module for tests only:

```html
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        DatePipe,
        JhiDataUtils,
        JhiDateUtils,
        JhiParseLinks,
        {
            provide: JhiLanguageService,
            useClass: MockLanguageService
        },
        {
            provide: JhiLanguageHelper,
            useClass: MockLanguageHelper
        },
        {
            provide: JhiEventManager,
            useClass:  MockEventManager
        },
        {
            provide: NgbActiveModal,
            useClass: MockActiveModal
        },
        {
            provide: ActivatedRoute,
            useValue: new MockActivatedRoute({id: 123})
        },
        {
            provide: Router,
            useClass: MockRouter
        },
        {
            provide: Principal,
            useClass: MockPrincipal
        },
        {
            provide: AccountService,
            useClass: MockAccountService
        },
        {
            provide: LoginModalService,
            useValue: null
        },
        {
            provide: ElementRef,
            useValue: null
        },
        {
            provide: Renderer,
            useValue: null
        },
        {
            provide: JhiAlertService,
            useValue: null
        },
        {
            provide: NgbModal,
            useValue: null
        },
    ],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule, RouterTestingModule ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
```

Now I want to test only one of the compoonets that is sharing the submodule.ts.  Providers,schemas and imports yess can be imported but entryComponents for example give errors. I was wondering if there is any rule on what should be imported and from which module??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subcomponent, only import the modules that you component use.

if you import your big modules, you will import **every module declared in it, along with every component, provider, directive, pipe (etc.) that are in it**. Imagine the time to mock all of it ...

For the `entryComponents`, there's a special syntax. I found it into Angualr Material's modal test, and I frankly don't want to search for the source now, so you'll have to take my word for it :

```
TestBed
  .configureTestingModule(...)
  .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [UploadModalComponent] } })
```

Comment: You mean import in the spec.ts file only the modules taht the component uses?

Comment: Sorry cause my question maybe is not very clear. I am asking what to import in spec.ts files, not in the components and modules. I am just testing it

Comment: `import in the spec.ts file only the modules taht the component uses?` → yes, exactly that. Import only what you use. For instance, instead of making a testing module, make several objects you can import separately. This isn't *required*, but it will save you some execution time when testing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What abou this question. Do you know anything? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100195/expected-to-have-attribute-disabled/51104934#51104934

Comment: No sorry, I have absolutely no knowledge about e2e, except for their purpose.

Comment: you dont need to know. the question is about jsdom, teh scripts inisde it do not execute. it only parses html

Comment: I don't know jsdom either, but I'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149104/how-to-test-using-chai-dom

Comment: You don´t have any idea about jsdom?

Comment: None. I don't even know what its purpose is. If you have an error in your console I'll be able to help (it's JS after all), but otherwise count on someone else.

Comment: There is no error. Just the attribute disabled of the button is not recognized because  I use jsdom to reference the html file and it doesnt run the scripts.

Comment: Well, stop using JDom then :D

Comment: but how? chai-dom needs using these document and window global var. But only jsdom can provide with them without jsdom it says documnet is not defined

Comment: As I told you, I have no idea about either e2e or JSDom. But I'm sure there's a way to do that.

Comment: if you had to do unit tests and you are using docuemnt.getEelmeemntById, and it says document is nt defined what do you do?

Comment: I would simply mock it, either with a spy (but I don't think you have access to jasmine), or with `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186547/ngform-controls-prints-undefined-in-angular this is unit testing. can you have  a look please? thanks