# ngForm.controls prints undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, undefined

I have this html to test in angular:

```
<form name="formCercarUsiari" #formCercarUsuari="ngForm" class="tab-content">
  <input #inputNif class="form-control input-height" maxlength="100" type="text" placeholder="Indiqui NIF" name="nif" i18n-placeholder="From placeholder">
</form>
```

Inside my compenent I take the reference like this:

```
@ViewChild('formCercarUsuari') formCercarUsuari: NgForm;
```

And in my test files:

```
fit('Name should be obligatory', async(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(component.formCercarUsuari);
    console.log('doesnt work' + component.formCercarUsuari.controls['nif']);
  });
}));
```

Now the first line `componet.forCercaUsuari prints: NgForm {.... controls,....},`
menawhile `componet.forCercaUsuari.controls` prints `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `component.formCercarUsuari.get('nif')`

Answer (score 0):

[As stated in the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#description):

> To register child controls with the form, you'll want to use `NgModel` with a `name` attribute.

```html
<form name="formCercarUsiari" #formCercarUsuari="ngForm" class="tab-content">
   <input #inputNif ngModel class="form-control input-height" maxlength="100" type="text" placeholder="Indiqui NIF" name="nif" i18n-placeholder="From placeholder">
</form>
```

That should give you access to your form input.